# mysql data updation based on previous record

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to database and using myPhpAdmin, in my table there is field **notification_icon** which include icon address, i put all image icons but i forget to add path of these icons which is common for all,

[image: column with image name only]

[image: column after image path added, i did this manually]

Is there any query to update image path in all, 
I tried:

```
UPDATE `notifications_notificationconfiguration` SET `notification_icon`="directory_path/"+`notification_icon`;
```

But this make all fields 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query you have will work for numeric data types eg `int` but for string data types eg `varchar` You should use [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
UPDATE `notifications_notificationconfiguration` 
SET `notification_icon`= CONCAT("directory_path/",notification_icon);
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/858e54/1/0)

Comment: Thanks, @Irfan , but how my query make all 0?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, your query is ok for numeric data types, you were using `+` to concatenate strings. `+` expects its operands to be numeric eg `1+integer_column`, when used on string column it will result in `0`

Comment: Thanks irfan, can you help me a bit longer, how i remove all directory_path from notification_icon, to revert my changes?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have tried it on live data with sample "directory_path/". Anyhow you can use `REPLACE`.

`SET notification_icon = REPLACE(notification_icon, 'directory_path/', '')`